# Why are these intervals true for this measurable function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$x \mapsto \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}; \\ 
 x, &\text{otherwise}. 
\end{cases}
$$

For all $A \in \mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})$, from the definition of measurability, the following holds:
$$
f^{-1}(A)=\begin{cases}
A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus  \mathbb{Q}), & \text{if } 0 \notin A; \\ 
(A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}))\cup \mathbb{Q}, &\text{if } 0 \in A. 
\end{cases}
$$

Can somebody explain why this holds from the definition of measurability?

Comment: it holds from set theory

Comment: I guess the question is rather "show that $f$ is measurable", then, as $f^{-1}(A)$ is an union/intersection of measurable sets, it's measurable then $f$ is measurable

Comment: @TsemoAristide that is too general! If you can explain more in details would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0 \in A$. If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) = 0 \in A$, so $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq f^{-1}(A)$. If $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) = x$. So, $f(x) \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A$. Therefore, $A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \subseteq f^{-1}(A)$. Since, $x$ is either in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, we have accounted for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So, we have shown that
$$
\text{if } 0 \in A \text{ then } f^{-1}(A) = \mathbb{Q} \cup [A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})].
$$

A similar kind of analysis will show that if $0 \not\in A$ then $f^{-1}(A) = A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$. All this comes from using concepts of set theory itself, there is no measure theory involved.